# Timeout if data from server is not received

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity's `WWW` class to get data from server. I am able to receive what I want, however I am looking for a way to use timeout here. Thing is, if there is an internet issue, the data will not be received. In this case I want a timeout function with an if statement. How do I achieve this?

```
IEnumerator GetData()
    {
        WWW data = new WWW("WEBSITE_TO_RECEIVE_DATA");
        yield return data;
        dataString = data.text;

        Items = dataString.Split(';');

        float Timer1 = int.Parse(Items[0]);
        float Timer2 = int.Parse(Items[1]);

        //If there is no internet then:
        //Timer1 = 10;
        //Timer2 = 20;
    }
```

Comment: Like the documentation says: You can check the isDone property. So when you want to idle for a given time do that and check at a given interval isDone till your timeout is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of connection problems Unity returns `www.isNetWorkError = true`. So first check for `www.isNetWorkError` before processing your response and break coroutine using `return` if it is true. Unity has its own timeout check in the background and eventually returns a `www` object even if there is no response from server.

If you don't want to wait for Unity's response, you need to manually implement a specific timeout. A practical way is to run another Coroutine in parallel that checks if you reached timeout and use a flag like `isTimeout = true`.

Than you can check it in your www coroutine before processing the response similar to checking isNetworkError. Or, assign a variable to your www coroutine and use `StopCoroutine()` to stop it so that it does not process any www result even if there is an error.

I'm giving both options in the sample code. You can pick one that fits your case.

```
 // First option.
 private IEnumerator getDataCoroutine;
 // Second option.
 private float timeOut = 10f;

 void GetData()
 {
    // First option.
    getDataCoroutine = GetData();
    StartCoroutine(getDataCoroutine);
    // Second option.        
    StartCoroutine(GetData);
    
    StartCoroutine(CheckGetDataTimeout);
}

IEnumerator CheckGetDataTimeout()
{
    float i = 0f;
    
    while (i < timeOut)
    {
        i += Time.deltaTime;
        // No timeout yet.
        yield return null;
    }
    
    // Request timeout.

    // First option:
    StopCoroutine(getDataCoroutine);
    // Second option:
    isTimeout = true;
}

IEnumerator GetData()
{
    WWW data = new WWW("WEBSITE_TO_RECEIVE_DATA");
    yield return data;

    if (data.isNetworkError)
    {
        return;
    }

    // First option.
    //   Nothing is necessary.
    // Second option.
    if (isTimeout)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    // Process response.
    dataString = data.text;
    // ...
}
```